# NSURLConnection did not work after cancel and immediately create

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I use NSURLConnection to establish a long polling connection to the server , and at some times ,i want to cancel the connection and rebuild the connection again. at first ,I wrote the code like this

```
[self.connect cancel];
self.connect = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[self.connect start];
```

but I found the connection delegate can't be called any more after this cancel&start.
so I use the dispatch

```
[self.connect cancel];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.connect = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [self.connect start];
});
```

And everything seems works fine at this time , but i was still don't know why the first choice (without dispatch) is not working?

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLConnection` needs a runloop to operate and there is one, by default, on the main thread.

However you would need to provide your own if you ran the connection on a non-main thread.

You might want to investigate using operation queues with `NSURLConnection` (for example you can set the delegate's `NSOperationQueue` or start an async connection on a specific queue).

Comment: sorry , I did quite understand this line "(for example you can set the delegate's NSOperationQueue or start an async connection on a specific queue)" ,do you mean that ,the gcd i used above has be changed to use operation queue?

Comment: @ximmyxiao Yeah that is simply misleading (I will correct).